Need help for enhanced Python Turtle code
I've been doing a course on Python. I've built the snake game - I'm amazed this could be done with just Turtle.
So I decided to enhance the game. I've spent the whole day on one extra enhancement: adding extra food.
What I wanted was, if the user scored x points, then they are rewarded with a big fruit that gives 5x points - but this fruit only sticks around for 5 seconds. The sticking around for 5 seconds is where I've got stuck.
I started by trying to keep things modular and put a loop in the newly created 'super_food.py' class. I think my logic was perfect. But when I ran the code, when the loop was running, the code slowed down to a really really low speed.
Then I moved the loop to the main.py file and I've been messing around with all day - but can't figure out how to work the logic and have a timer that removes after x seconds the 'super food'.
Here's the code I have from main.py:
from turtle import Screen
from snake import Snake
from food import Food
from super_food import SuperFood
from scoreboard import Scoreboard
import time

SPEED_IN_TIME = 0.1
ACCURACY = 45 # This determines how close we get to the snake to determine a hit
ACCURACY_COLLISION = 10
BONUS_SCORE_OCCUR = 3
SUPER_FOOD_DURATION = 5

super_food_exists = False # Trying a hack to see if I can add super food - I've been struggling with this one all day
start_time = 0 # This is used in the super_food code

# All these we don't have in the Snake Class - these are separate to the snake
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
Y_EDGE = screen.window_height() // 2
X_EDGE = screen.window_height() // 2

screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.title("My Snake Game with super food Gemini Version")
screen.tracer(0) # We turn off screen animation - this was making the movements look jagged.

snake = Snake()
food = Food()
super_food = SuperFood() # We add the new Super Food
scoreboard = Scoreboard()

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(snake.up, "Up")
screen.onkey(snake.down, "Down")
screen.onkey(snake.left, "Left")
screen.onkey(snake.right, "Right")

game_is_on = True

temp_time_controller = False

while game_is_on:

    screen.update()
    time.sleep(SPEED_IN_TIME)

    snake.move()

    # Let's detect collision with food
    if snake.head.distance(food) < ACCURACY:
        # We have a hit! So we need to have the food appear elsewhere and increase the score
        food.refresh()

        # Now we increase the score
        scoreboard.increase_score()

        # We increase the lenght of the snake
        snake.extend()

    # print(snake.head.xcor()) # Just testing I can access the x coordinate

    if snake.head.xcor() > X_EDGE or snake.head.xcor() < -X_EDGE or snake.head.ycor() > Y_EDGE or snake.head.ycor() < -Y_EDGE:
        game_is_on = False
        scoreboard.game_over()

    # Nearly finished! Now we write code to detect if the snake colides with itself
    for segment in snake.turtle_segments[1:]:
        if snake.head.distance(segment) < ACCURACY_COLLISION:
            game_is_on = False
            scoreboard.game_over()

    # New part adding: super foods
    if scoreboard.score != 0: # Problem was 0 % BONUS_SCORE_OCCUR == 0
        if scoreboard.score % BONUS_SCORE_OCCUR == 0:

            super_food_exists = True

            start_time = time.time() # We start of the timer

        if super_food_exists:

            if time.time() - start_time < SUPER_FOOD_DURATION:
                print(f"Time check: {time.time() - start_time < SUPER_FOOD_DURATION}")
                print(f"Time check: {int(time.time() - start_time)}")
                super_food.unhide()
            else:
                super_food.hide()
                super_food_exists = False
                # start_time = 0
        # else:
        #     super_food.hide()

screen.exitonclick()

I'm guessing threading would help here - having the countdown run in its own thread?
Is it possible to do without threading? I'm completely saturated and can't think straight.
Thanks.
I was expecting the code to run with my new addition - it nearly works!

For starters, use ontimer rather than while True:. Secondly, provide all files necessary to run the code, and remove anything irrelevant so the code is minimal. See [mcve] for help. I'd also choose a specific title that actually describes your problem. Avoid conversational sidelines like "can't think straight", and focus on asking specific technical questions: "how can I run an event every 5 seconds in my snake game using turtle?" for example.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a specific question - which will come out of your best attempt to understand and locate a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the specific part of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely expect something), and don't understand why.

It is not possible to "help you" here as this is not a discussion forum. Instead, figure out what the concrete problem to solve is, and state it as directly and clearly as possible.

If you provide the missing code to run the game, I will consider to fix the issues you are experiencing.

One option could be to keep a timer variable in the super_food.py file, then use datetime.datetime.now to save the time it was created and then everytime you update the screen do a subtraction between the previous time and the new current time, like this,
#inside the super food file
then = datetime.datetime.now()

#inside the updating loop, 
now = datetime.datetime.now()
deltaTime = now - then
if deltaTime > 5:
    # do whatever you need to make it disappear

